# Mongoose populate is not working, returns undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

```
app.get("/index/:id", function(req, res)
{
  campgrounds.findById({ _id: req.params.id }).populate("comment").exec(
    function(error, foundscamp) {
        console.log(foundscamp);
        if (error) {
            consol.log(error);
            console.log("you gotcha error");
        } else {
            //render the show page with sopecific id
            res.render("show.ejs", { foundcamps: foundscamp });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: `consol.log()` is not a valid function

Answer (score 0):

If we look the **mongoosejs** documentation about [findById](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#findbyid_findById):

> #### Model.findById()
>
> Finds a single document by its `_id` field. `findById(id)` is almost* equivalent to `findOne({ _id: id })`. If you want to query by a document's `_id`, use `findById()` instead of `findOne()`.
>
> - Except for how it treats undefined. If you use `findOne()`, you'll see that `findOne(undefined)` and `findOne({ _id: undefined })` are equivalent to `findOne({})` and return arbitrary documents. However, mongoose translates `findById(undefined`) into `findOne({ _id: null })`.

You can see that the problem is that `findById()` consumes an `_id`, not a json `{ _id : id }`. So change:

```
campgrounds.findById({ _id: req.params.id })...
```

to

```
campgrounds.findById({ req.params.id })...
```

The rest of the code looks fine (apart from the `consol.log()` pointed by [Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4569506/daniel)).

Comment: @VivekJaiswal With the infomation you provide.. No.

Comment: null
TypeError: C:\Users\Vivek\Desktop\MY PRACTICE\NODE JS BASICS\yelpcamp\views\show.ejs:6
    4| <div>
    5|     <p>
 >> 6|         <%=foundcamps.name %>
    7|     </p>
    8|     <img src="<%= foundcamps.image %>" alt="">
    9|     <p>

Cannot read property 'name' of null

Comment: I think is better to update your Post with the new information. But what I can see in your comment, that is a problem in your `show.ejs`, so what I will do in you position would be to isolate the problem, maybe the problem is in your view or maybe is in your `findById`. I see that you have a `console.log(foundscamp);` do you get the desire output there?

Comment: Now populate is working but still ...my findby id is not working

Comment: How is your `populate ` working but the `findById` is not? could you please update your question with the error you get?? and with the updated code?

Comment: That looks like another type of error. You could accept this answer and create a new one, where you post all the details about the cast error, in that way I can help you and other users can help as well.

Comment: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): ValidationError: resources validation failed: comments: Cast to [undefined] failed for value "[{"_id":"5a736be575ca624088cc4596","text":"yeah cool place","author":"vivek","__v":0}]" at path "comments"
(node:16520) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code......................how this error remove i cant understand...